# Receiving binary data instead of XML using HTTPService?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

- Is there a way to receive binary data instead of XML when using HTTPService with Flex application ?
  *( ASP .NET 4 backend / Flex 4.8 framework )*

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437685/flex-send-http-post-request-with-binary-data-in-body)

Comment: @Varnius That is for sending; not receiving.  In this case; I'm guessing on the server side you'll want to mime-type encode it somehow before sending it back.  On the HTTPService, set the resultFormat to text.  The turn the results into a byteArray.

Comment: this is interesting idea actually Flextras. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far the only solution i know about is as shown in here:
http://anirudhsasikumar.net/blog/2008.06.20.html