# Sending a bitmapData over network - as3

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, flash, c#-4.0, air

I am trying to send a bitmapdata to the server(written in C#) from the client(written in as3).
The server after receiving the bitmapData should add the image to a folder in a given location. I am sending the filename along with the bitmapData to the server. I am able to read the filename but I am unable to read the bitmapData on the server side. It keeps throwing "ArgumentExceptionOccured - Parameter is not valid" exception.

Could anyone tell me how to send an image from the client(as3) to the server(C#) please?

Client Side code:

```
function onScreenCaptureClick(event:MouseEvent):Void
{
var filename:String = "TEST123";
var myBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
myBitmapData.draw(stage);

// Custom Network class which contains the 'openNetworkToken' method to send the image to the         server
Network.OpenNetworkToken("ADDIMAGE" + "|" + filename + "|" + myBitmapData);    
}
```

Server side code:

```
private void onAddImagesHandler(MessageEventArgs args)
  {
        if (args.IsTokenized)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("### CREATE MESSAGE RECEIVED ###");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Message: " + args.OriginalMessage);

            try
            {
                 string filename = args.Arguements[0];

                 Bitmap img = new Bitmap(args.Arguements[1]); // "ArgumentExceptionOccured - Parameter is not valid"
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
            args.SendResponse("ImageADDED", true);
        }

    }
```

Any help appreciated

Thanks,
Vinu

Comment: you should start by showing how you send the data.

Comment: You haven't posted the way you send the BitmapData from AS3.0, or the rest of the C# code, but something tells me you aren't encoding it probably (or at all) - that is, AS3.0 encodes the data somehow, which is not compatible with the way C# decodes it and requires it.

Comment: @Aurel300: I am not encoding the bitmapData. I am just sending it across the network as it is. I have never worked on Networking before.

Comment: Have you checked the length of `args.Arguements` in your c# code?  The problem is most likely with encoding as @Aurel300 stated, but it won't hurt to double-check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your Bitmap to a PNG and send it Base64 encoded with this code:

```
var byteArray:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
myBitmapData.encode(new Rectangle(0,0,640,480), new flash.display.PNGEncoderOptions(), byteArray); 
var encoder:Base64Encoder = new Base64Encoder();
encoder.encodeBytes(byteArray);

Network.OpenNetworkToken("ADDIMAGE" + "|" + filename + "|" + encoder.toString());
```

There are much more efficient ways to transmit the data if you can change your Network class to suit.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1438199/514087 for the basic outline of that approach.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I debugged the code and I can now see that the bitmapData has been encoded and sent to the server. I will decode it on my server and keep you updated with the ptogress